# Como utilizar a classe SharedPreferencesUtils.java?

Tags: java, android

Desculpem pelo titulo, não sei como seria outra forma melhor de perguntar.

Estou aprendendo a programar em aplicativos android, e encontrei uma classe em JAVA para facilitar o uso de **SharedPreferences**. Mas eu não entendi muito bem em como utilizar.

Achei o código [aqui.](Https://gist.github.com/lopspower/dec2592872f8df65a26c)

E o código é esse:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

/**
 * Copyright (C) 2016 Mikhael LOPEZ
 * Licensed under the Apache License Version 2.0
 * Utility class for the SharedPreferences management
 */
public class SharedPreferencesUtils {

    // PUBLIC PREF NAME
    public static final String PREFS_EXAMPLE = "example";

    //region Singleton Shared Preferences
    private static final String PREFS_FILE_NAME = "PrefsFile";
    private static SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;

    private static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferencesEditor(Context context) {
        if (mSharedPreferences == null) {
            mSharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        }
        return mSharedPreferences;
    }
    //endregion

    public static void setString(Context context, String name, String value) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferencesEditor(context).edit();
        editor.putString(name, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public static String getString(Context context, String name) {
        return getSharedPreferencesEditor(context).getString(name, null);
    }

    public static void remove(Context context, String name) {
        getSharedPreferencesEditor(context).edit().remove(name).commit();
    }

}
```

Eu não entendi o porque ele colocou aquele **example** ali e o **PrefsFile** em *private*.

Seria melhor incrementar este código para alterar esses dados com um constructor?

Eu estou usando desta forma por enquanto:

`SharedPreferencesUtils.setString(getApplicationContext(), "userLogged", varuserlogged);`

e

`UsernameLogged = SharedPreferencesUtils.getString(getApplicationContext(),"userLogged");`

Está funcionando assim, mas está certo isso? Só Que ele salva sempre num arquivo chamado `PrefsFile.xml`. Se eu quiser separar as preferencias acho que precisaria modificar essa classe. Alguém tem alguma ideia melhor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O nome do arquivo usado é aquele que a declaração da classe atribuiu ao campo `PREFS_FILE_NAME`.

Se pretende poder indicar outro nome para o arquivo deverá sobrescrever os métodos públicos `setString()`, `getString()` e `remove()` acrescentando um parâmetro que receba o nome do arquivo a usar. O método privado `getSharedPreferencesEditor()` necessita de ser alterado de forma a lidar com esse requisito.

Aplicando as alterações e simplificações, a classe ficará assim:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class SharedPreferencesUtils {

    private static final String DEFAULT_PREFS_FILE_NAME = "PrefsFile";

    private static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferencesEditor(Context context, String fileName) {    
        return context.getSharedPreferences(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public static void setString(Context context, String name, String value) {
        setString(context, name, value, DEFAULT_PREFS_FILE_NAME);
    }

    public static void setString(Context context, String name, String value, String fileName) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferencesEditor(context, fileName).edit();
        editor.putString(name, value);
        editor.commit();
    }


    public static String getString(Context context, String name) {
        return getString(context, name, DEFAULT_PREFS_FILE_NAME);
    }

    public static String getString(Context context, String name, String fileName) {
        return getSharedPreferencesEditor(context, fileName).getString(name, null);
    }

    public static void remove(Context context, String name) {
        remove(context, name, DEFAULT_PREFS_FILE_NAME);
    }

    public static void remove(Context context, String name, String fileName) {
        getSharedPreferencesEditor(context, fileName).edit().remove(name).commit();
    }
}
```

Quando quiser usar um arquivo diferente passe o seu nome ao último parâmetro de cada um dos métodos públicos:

```
SharedPreferencesUtils.setString(getApplicationContext(), "userLogged", varuserlogged, "NomeDoArquivo");
```

e

```
UsernameLogged = SharedPreferencesUtils.getString(getApplicationContext(),"userLogged", "NomeDoArquivo");
```

Comment: Obrigada moço, perfeito, ainda não testei, mas entendi perfeitamente as suas mudanças e explicação, ficou bem melhor agora. Irei utilizar dessa forma. Mais uma vez obrigada!! bjss

Answer (score 0):

PREF_EXAMPLE não é usado no código. 
A variável PREFS_FILE foi mantida privado apenas para na alterar o local onde é salvo.

O que essa classe faz é encapsular código para que não seja necessário copiar e colar trechos de código.

Sobre o modo privado ele indica que apenas o seu aplicativo pode ler aquela informação.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_PRIVATE

Vale a pena ler sobre shared preferences.
Eis o link: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html?hl=pt-br

Comment: Você não entendeu minha pergunta moço, eu to falando sobre essa linha aqui: `private static final String PREFS_FILE_NAME = "PrefsFile";` estar em private, pois obriga todas preferencias ser apenas num único arquivo.

Comment: e sobre esta linhas `public static final String PREFS_EXAMPLE = "example";` que não estou entendendo a utilidade dela no código. E tbm sobre um modo de fazer essa classe ficar melhor para utilizar, e se estou utilizando direito. Sobre SharedPreferences eu ja sei usar, e o MODE_PRIVATE também. mesmo assim obrigado por responder.

Comment: atualizei a resposta